# html export table to excel right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, export-to-excel

I am trying to export a table to excel, I can do it but the sheet is left to right, I want it to be right to left. of course I can do it manually (`Page Layout -> Sheet right-to-left`), but I want it to be automatically.
I'm using for the exporting **jquery.table2excel.js**:

```js
//table2excel.js
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    var pluginName = "table2excel",
        defaults = {
            exclude: ".noExl",
            name: "Table2Excel"
        };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        // jQuery has an extend method which merges the contents of two or
        // more objects, storing the result in the first object. The first object
        // is generally empty as we don't want to alter the default options for
        // future instances of the plugin
        this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            var e = this;
            e.template = "<html xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-    com:office:excel\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>";
            e.template += "<x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions>";
            e.template += "<x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>";
            e.tableRows = "";

            // get contents of table except for exclude
            $(e.element).find("tr").not(this.settings.exclude).each(function(i, o) {
                e.tableRows += "<tr>" + $(o).html() + "</tr>";
            });
            this.tableToExcel(this.tableRows, this.settings.name);
        },
        tableToExcel: function(table, name) {
            var e = this;
            e.uri = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,";
            e.base64 = function(s) {
                return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
            };
            e.format = function(s, c) {
                return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
                    return c[p];
                });
            };
            e.ctx = {
                worksheet: name || "Worksheet",
                table: table
            };
            window.location.href = e.uri + e.base64(e.format(e.template, e.ctx));
        }
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
        this.each(function() {
            if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
            }
        });

        // chain jQuery functions
        return this;
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

I think its something in the **WorksheetOptions** area, but I can't figure out what.

The HTML code is simple, just filling the table, and using **TableSorter.js** to enable sorting.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
 <x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayRightToLeft/> </x:WorksheetOptions>
```

You can see more options:[here](https://stigmortenmyre.no/mso/html/excel/xleleexcelworkbook.htm)